# Commenting conventions in Java

Tags: java, arrays, comments

All Java developers do know the conventions for commenting using *slashslash* (`// Comment`) and *slashstar* (`/* Comment */`). But I came across a documentation of [JSONArray of codehaus](https://github.com/codehaus/jettison/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/jettison/json/JSONArray.java), starting from line 69:

> Comments written in the slashshlash, slashstar, and hash conventions will be ignored.

What is hash conventions? How is it used? Couldn't get the relevant good result googling it.

Comment: `# This is a comment`? And, no, Java doesn't support it ;)

Comment: # for comments only exist in languages like Ruby and Python, not in Java though

Comment: Can you give me the line number of the line that says "Comments written in the slashshlash, slashstar, and hash conventions will be ignored."? I can't find it.

Comment: @Sweeper Line 69.

Comment: These are non-standard JSON document comments, jettison allows you to do it more flexible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are linking to the documentation of a JSON parser, so this is not about comments in Java, but comments in JSON.

In standard JSON, there is no syntax for comments *at all*.

This parser is more flexible and allows comments in three popular varieties:

```
{  "x":  1,      // slash-slash
   "y":  2,       /*  slash-star 
                 */
   "z":  3       # hash
}
```

You cannot use these comments in portable JSON, but if those are files that stay inside of your system and will be run through that particular parser, this is quite convenient (and you cannot use "hash" comments in Java).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I went through JSON specifications and documentation as well, but nothing was written about hash conventions.